# Collapsible content with checkbox in header

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to realize a collapsible list with a checkbox in each header. Selecting (checking) should only working if you click exactly on the checkbox. Otherwise the header should collapse, and the additional details are visible.

Here an example, how it should looks like:

[image: Example with picture editor]

My try, but without the checkbox implementation:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="col1" data-iconpos="right">

    <h3> Header 1</h3>
    <p>More Informationen about Header 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" id="col2">
         <h3>Header 2</h3>

        <p>More Informationen about Header 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" id="col3">
         <h3>Header 3</h3>

        <p>More Informationen about Header 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6t7bhbgc/11/

Comment: check this out [collapse when checkbox checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480524/twitter-bootstrap-3-collapse-when-checkbox-checked/29202309)

Comment: It's using bootstrap. I want realize it with jquery.