# Why Bootstrap 3 Collapse is not synchronized with checkbox state on double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

According to this question: "[Twitter Bootstrap 3 collapse when checkbox checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22480524/twitter-bootstrap-3-collapse-when-checkbox-checked)" i've tried this solution, because it is simple and clean.

http://jsfiddle.net/L0h3s7uf/1/

```
<div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h4 class="panel-title">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
                    <input type="checkbox"/> I have Driver License  
                </label>
            </div>
                                  </h4>

        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="driving-license-kind">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">A</div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">B</div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">C</div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">D</div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">E</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But with this "solution" you have a problem. If you click the checkbox too fast, the area is collapsed but the checkbox is checked.

How can i prevent this double clicking problem?

I am using:

- Bootstrap 3
- jQuery 3.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no double click handling in bootstrap for toggle specially, so I come up with a special work around to make double click in sync.

I just removed `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute, added `#testCheckBox` **id** to checkbox's parent `div` and I did some custom script which detect if double click or single click then validate the checkbox values and toggle on their bases:

```
$('.collapse').collapse();

$("#testCheckBox :checkbox").bind('click dblclick', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.type);

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.collapse').slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        $('.collapse').slideUp('fast');
    }
})
```

**demo:** https://jsbin.com/ciloliweto/edit?html,output

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: my pleasure, hopefully you get the idea :)

Answer (score 3):

Disable the checkbox while collapsing:

http://jsfiddle.net/L0h3s7uf/220/

```
<input id="license_check_box" type="checkbox"/> I have Driver License   

$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#license_check_box').prop('disabled', true);
}).on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#license_check_box').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Good solution, but I used @mumair 's solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is a general solution copied from @IanMetten to get all and fix collapsable controls.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function() {
        var $control=$(this);       
        var $target=$($control.attr("data-target"));
        $target.on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function() {
            $control.prop('disabled', true);
        }).on('shown.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
            $control.prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work for You

```js
$('.collapse').collapse()
$("#check").one('click', function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           //do something
        
     });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.panel-body {
    padding: 4px 50px;
}
</style>
     
    <div class="panel-group driving-license-settings" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4 class="panel-title">
                                          <div class="checkbox">
                    <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check"/> I have Driver License  
                    </label>
                </div>
                                      </h4>

            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="driving-license-kind">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">A</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">B</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">C</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">D</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="">E</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not solution, I think problem is with double click

Comment: check again i have also tested that i am not facing that problem

Comment: I don't understand your solution, if you doubleclick the checkbox, multiple times the checkbox state is asynchron to the collapse div.

Comment: @adityashrivastava try multiple time double clicks and watch

Comment: wait i will give u this solution